# When starting the wso2 API Manager Analytics 2.1.0 I get the error below. The DB is cassandra

Tags: cassandra, wso2, wso2-api-manager

When starting the wso2 API Manager Analytics 2.1.0 I get the error below. The DB is cassandra

```
2017-08-01 11:39:17,472] [EI-Analytics] ERROR {org.wso2.carbon.analytics.dataservice.core.AnalyticsDataServiceComponent} -      Error in activating analytics data service: All host(s) tried for query failed     (tried: localhost/127.0.0.1:9042 (com.datastax.driver.core.exceptions.InvalidQueryException: unconfigured table schema_keyspaces))  
com.datastax.driver.core.exceptions.NoHostAvailableException: All host(s) tried for query failed   
(tried: localhost/127.0.0.1:9042 (com.datastax.driver.core.exceptions.InvalidQueryException: unconfigured table schema_keyspaces))
```

Comment: What is the cassandra version? WSO2 Analytics supports only 2.0.x or 2.1.x versions. - https://docs.wso2.com/display/DAS300/Configuring+Data+Persistence+With+Cassandra

Comment: Earlier I was using apache-cassandra-3.11.0 But I tried with apache-cassandra-2.1.0 as well but getting same error.

Comment: Check if the necessary number of nodes are up to satisfy consistency level.

Comment: yes,the necessary number of nodes are up to satisfy consistency level

Comment: are you sure your cassandra listens to localhost aka 127.0.0.1? that's often not the case

Comment: Yes we are sure.

Answer (score 1):

This is your problem:

```
InvalidQueryException: unconfigured table schema_keyspaces
```

In Cassandra 3.x, `schema_keyspaces` doesn't exist in the `system` keyspace any longer.  My guess is that WSO2 has a hard-coded Cassandra integration to pull schema from `system.schema_keyspaces` and `system.schema_columnfamilies`.

As of 2.2, that data is now stored in the `system_schema` keyspace, in `system_schema.keyspaces` and `system_schema.tables`.

> I tried with apache-cassandra-2.1.0 as well but getting same error.

Not sure what to tell you there, as that keyspace *does* exist in 2.1.

If you're going to use 2.1.x, make sure to grab 2.1.18.  A lot of fixes have gone in since 2.1.0.  If a clean install of that doesn't work, I suppose you could try 2.0.17 from the archives, but I don't recommend that.

But to be fair, I don't recommend middleware from companies that [pawn their support off on StackOverflow](http://wso2.com/support/#Community-Support), either.

Comment: Tried with 2.1.18 too but no any success till now.